# Click to call HTML/Javascript - Display name of company as caller ID when calling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A little difficult to explain - But when on a phone on Google, and you tap the phone number of a business to call them, the phone app opens but instead of showing the number you're calling, it shows the company name.

What is the best method to achieve this? I know this uses Javascript, but I wouldn't know where to begin with targeting.

I have a typical `<a href="tel:01234567890">` that I'm working with here on a webpage.

Any suggestions, or a point in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide example where this `tel:` link has company name when clicked? Do you have this company number in address book?

Comment: Type any business name into Google on your mobile, click the 'call' button and you'll see the company name instead of the number as it's dialing. I see that it functions using Javascript, so maybe there's a library that does this.

No I don't have any of these in my address book, I've made dozens of calls this way through Google and every time the company name comes up.